# Experiences with Google TiSP?

Tags: linux, internet

i got an email from google a couple of hours ago (around 12AM EST today) that Google's [TiSP](http://www.google.com/tisp/) service is now available in my area.

this seems like a great deal compared to my cUrrent 16Mbps cable coNction at work, however i'm a lIttle nervous about the fact that linux support is "Coming soon". i was wOndering if anyone had successfully installed this system and gotten it woRking with their linux infrastructure? I'm assuming that there shouldn't be any issues siNce we have an ASA in front of our internet.

TiSP Shouldn't care what is behind that.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Warner, if April Fools humor bugs you then you should probably not even open a browser for the next ~36 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer you exclusively to todays date.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. They ran that promotion a few years ago, never really took off. Maybe I'll give em a call, see if they offer it in my area this time.